# Inferring (at compile-time) which members are read inside method

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, template-meta-programming, sfinae, compile-time

Consider this code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

// Random structs that follow this pattern
struct X { int         x; using Type = int; };
struct Y { float       y; using Type = float; };
struct Z { const char* z; using Type = const char*; };
struct W { double      w; using Type = double; };

// Struct composed via inheritance
struct S : X, Y, Z, W
{
    // This method reads `x` and nothing else
    Y::Type MethodY() const
    {
        // Some random logic
        return static_cast<float>(x) * 10.0F;
    }

    // This methods reads `x`, `y` and `z`
    W::Type MethodW() const
    {
        // Some random logic again
        return z ? static_cast<double>(y) : static_cast<double>(x);
    }

    // Imagine there may be more such methods
    // ...
};

template<auto Method>
using WhatMethodReads = std::tuple</* List of bases of `S` that are used in `Method` */>;

// Goal:
static_assert(std::is_same_v<WhatMethodReads<&S::MethodY>, std::tuple<X>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<WhatMethodReads<&S::MethodW>, std::tuple<X, Y, Z>>);

int main() { }
```

**Problem**: basically, given the method, I want to infer (at compile-time) which particular members the method reads inside its body.

In the sample particularly, I construct the type via multiple inheritance, so each member is strongly tied to a dedicated struct; but if there are solutions that work with other way of composition, those are welcomed as well.

The method may be a free function instead that takes a const ref to `S`, it doesn't really matter.

### What I tried

I tried to test whether method compiles or not while changing public inheritance to private (thus hiding members) or by removing those bases entirely using template metaprogramming. I was expecting SFINAE to pick alternative specialization when method doesn't compile without a particular base (like, I remove, base `Y` from `A`: `MethodW` body is now ill-formed - it means that `MethodW` does depend on `Y` so it goes into resulting tuple of `WhatMethodReads<&S::MethodW>`; on the other hand `MethodY` is still well-formed when I remove that same `Y` so `Y` won't go into `WhatMethodReads<&S::MethodY>`).

The problem is that when compiler sees access to private member of base (or non-existing member), it just stops the compilation with error instead of applying SFINAE rules.

So, this approach boils down to implementing a legal way to get bool constexpr value that tells whether function body is well-formed ot not. This would be sufficient to solve my problem.

Sample of implementation attempt:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
auto Function()
{
    // Imagine usage is much more complicated
    // and assume that `requires { T + T; }`
    // doesn't suffice for me. I want substitution
    // in other place to fail based on whether this
    // function is well-formed or not.
    return T{} + T{};
}

template<class T>
struct IsFunctionLegal : std::false_type
{ };

template<class T>
    // So, one of the attempts was to declare that
    // function return type is `auto` and then
    // use `decltype` in some way to infer
    // whether function body is legal or not.
    // But it results in compile error instead of SFINAE.
    requires requires { std::is_same_v<decltype(Function<T>()), T>; }
struct IsFunctionLegal<T> : std::true_type
{ };

int main()
{
    std::cout << IsFunctionLegal<int>::value;  // fine, returns true
    std::cout << IsFunctionLegal<void>::value; // error instead of false
}
```

Error:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'auto Function() [with T = void]':
<source>:25:60:   required by substitution of 'template<class T>  requires requires{is_same_v<decltype((Function<T>)()), T>;} struct IsFunctionLegal<T> [with T = void]'
<source>:32:39:   required from here
<source>:12:16: error: invalid operands of types 'void' and 'void' to binary 'operator+'
   12 |     return T{} + T{};
      |            ~~~~^~~~~
Build failed
```

Comment: *I want to infer (at compile-time) which particular members the method reads inside its body.*  I'm afraid to ask why you want/need this and not just a static analyzer.

Comment: I doubt this is possible now or would even be possible with Reflection because, practically speaking, the compiler would have to use, in compile time, information about functions which may only be available at link time, which would be problematic for static linking and impossible for dynamic linking. So, there would be limitations on which functions such reflection can be used on even if it was possible, i.e. at least their definition would have to be available to compiler at the point of acquiring such information.

Comment: "tells whether function body is well-formed ot not" This is not possible. "it just stops the compilation with error instead of applying SFINAE" That's how things work. A substitution failure (SF in SFINAE) is a very specific thing, and your error is not that thing.